# Guess another's present 2: Generalised

Tags: logical-deduction, hat-guessing

What if in [Guess another's present](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24731/guess-anothers-present) problem introduce more present's colours? Also i would reduce a number of men to number of colours. So the task basically the following:

> N clever men receive presents from the president. There are N possible colors of present. Each man knows the color of his own gift only.
>
> Then each man must guess a colour of a gift of some man: he must chose a man (besides himself) and a colour, write these down on a piece of paper and give this paper to an organiser. Once all this is done the organiser counts amount of correct guesses out of N.
>
> The men know all the described procedure in advance and have time to develop a strategy, before receiving any presents. Once they receive the presents, they will be unable to communicate with each other.
>
> Their task is to guarantee maximum amount of correct guesses. Your task is to say 1) what is this maximum amount, 2) what can be a strategy of the men and 3) prove that there is no other strategy, which can guaranty a bigger amount.

@Mike Earnest gave a quite clear [proof](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/24748/28) that for such a task it is impossible to guarantee more than N/N=1 correct guess. When N=2 it is quite easy to guarantee 1 correct guess: see [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/24732/28) of @The Dark Truth. But already with N=3 i'm failing to figure out a strategy.

Also note that the task is quite similar to well known [N logicians wearing hats of N colors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70/n-logicians-wearing-hats-of-n-colors/405#405) problem. The differences are: 1. a man sees only his "hat", not "hats" of all others, 2. a man must guess another person color and he can chose this person, he is not stuck with guessing his own "hat" color.

Comment: tough one for sure, I'm actually leaning towards it not being possible but will be happy if someone proves me wrong. It would be possible ofcourse if you had $N^2$ men or if people didn't know their own gift but were allowed to choose themselves.

Comment: @DrunkWolf, N^2?  for N colours? N+1 men should be enough for easy solution.

Comment: it's enough to get 1 correct guess yes, but not to get 1/Nth of guesses correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a correct guess cannot be guaranteed for any $N\geq 3$.

The key idea, [pointed out by Mike Earnest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/24748/4551), is that the expected number of correct guesses is the number of people divided by the number of colors, here $1$. So, if ever there are $2$ or more correct guesses, some other state must lead to $0$ incorrect guesses to compensate. Therefore, any winning strategy must always give *exactly* $1$ correct guess. We can imagine the players simply lose if two or more of them guess right.

Say that player P *considers* player Q if some color of P would make them guess Q's color.

First, note that considering is symmetric. Say that P considers Q, specifically that when P is red, he guesses that Q is green. If Q is indeed green, then P must guess wrong to avoid two correct guesses. The only guaranteed wrong guess for Q is that P is a color other than red, so Q considers P. (Extending this reasoning for later use, if green Q guesses, say, blue P, then blue P must guess Q as well.)

Moreover, any two pairs of players that consider each other must have a player in common. Otherwise, both pairs could have a correct guess. This requires that there is a player who considers everyone. It only remains to rule this out for $N \geq 3$.

Note from before that if P considers Q, he must dedicate at least two of his colors to guessing Q. So, any player considers at most half the other players, which for $N\geq 3$ rules out a player who considers everyone.